# Estimating Moving Average Impact Matrix after running VECM

Tags: r, time-series, vector-error-correction-model, orthogonal

How to estimate moving average impact matrix after running VECM model in R? It is given as $ \hat{\beta_c}( \hat{\alpha_c}$ $\hat{\Gamma}$ $\hat{\beta_c}$)$^{-1}$ $\hat{\alpha_c}'$, where $\alpha$, $\Gamma$ and $\beta$ are parameters extracted from the VECM model, and c refers to the orthogonal complement.

My question is how to find the orthogonal complements of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and also whether the signs of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ needs to be reversed before implementing that? I have gone through a lot of sources but can't find a way to solve this.

The way I am estimating VECM:

```r
  cointest <- ca.jo(x, K = nlag, type = "eigen", ecdet = "const",
                    spec = "longrun")  
  k <- cointest@lag
  vecm <- cajorls(cointest)
```

I am using `nullcomplement` package in R to find an orthogonal complement. But, it is giving me a null space.